# How do I get a SP into a string?

Tags: asp.net, string, ado.net

I Dont know how to get my stored Procedures value into a String.

This is my guess but dosent work:

```
string id = Request.QueryString["ProductID"];
String Color = GetColor(id);
```

The GetColor(id) should be blue, but is "", and my String Color is "".

```
public static DataTable GetColor(string ProductID)
{
    DbCommand comm = GenericDataAccess.CreateCommand();

    comm.CommandText = "GetColor";

    DbParameter param = comm.CreateParameter();
    param.ParameterName = "@ProductID";
    param.Value = ProductID;
    param.DbType = DbType.Int32;
    comm.Parameters.Add(param);

    DataTable table = GenericDataAccess.ExecuteSelectCommand(comm);
    return table;
}


ALTER PROCEDURE GetColor
@ProductID INT AS Select Color from tblColor where ProductID = @ProductID
```

Comment: Could you post a bit more of your code so we can see how you are making a call to the database?

Comment: Okey, I've added some more code, what do you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you set a breakpoint at `return table;` and inspected the returned result.
If the table is filled correctly then you will need to use
`String Color = GetColor(id).Rows[0][0];`

For your comment:

```
DataTable result = GetColor(id);
string Color = result.Rows[0][0];
string Price = result.Rows[0][1];
string Width = result.Rows[0][2];
```

But you need to inspect the result DataTable and its first row to make sure you have populated it correctly. Try to inspect `result.Rows[0]` in the quick watch window

Comment: Great! Thanks alot! Works great! I have two more values that I would like to get from the same SP. Can I get that value from the same query or do I have to make the call three times?

Comment: String Color, String Price, string Width = GetColor(id).Rows[0][0]; Dosent work that good

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that it's because your method is returning a DataTable, which doesn't cast directly to a string. I think something like GetColor(id).Rows[0][0] would work?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use ExecuteScalar here -- no reason at all to create a datatable to get a single value.